# jQuery on click of single button toggle between 2 HTML files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to programming so please bear with me.  I have a single button where when you click it, it'll go to another HTML file, but when I click it again, it won't go back to the other HTML file it was previously on. Essentially I want to toggle between the two (or more if I add additional pages).

Trying to do this only with jQuery.

```
$(".button").on("click", function() {
    if(window.location.href = "index1.html"){
        window.location.replace("index2.html");
    }

});

$(".button").on("click", function () {
    if (window.location.href = "index2.html") {
        window.location.replace("index1.html");
    }
});
```

This seems overcomplicated for a task like this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your conditionals should have double equals signs (`==`) to **compare**. A single equals sign **assigns**. You can also use triple equals signs (`===`) to additionally compare the **type**.

Comment: `I want to toggle between the two (or more if I add additional pages)`
This isn't clear to me. You cant toggle between more than 2 pages with out a clear definition of which page to toggle to out of the 3 or more pages. By toggle, do you actually mean move in sequence? E.g. Index2.html -> index3.html -> etc ?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear message, but yes. If I have index1.html, index2.html, and index3.html, on click it would cycle through them all in sequence. On index3.html, on click of the button, it'd go back to index1.html if that makes sense.

Comment: `window.location.href = 'newaddress';` opens a new document which may or may not has that button and that JS.

Answer (score 1):

If these two blocks of code are in the same file, the second `onclick` event is overriding the first. `window.location` might also be enough if you just need to redirect.

Try this:

```
$(".button").on("click", function() {
    if(window.location.href == "index1.html"){
        window.location="index2.html";
    }else if(window.location.href == "index2.html"){
        window.location="index1.html";
    }
});
```

Comment: @obsidian he also doing the same error. @Eyzi please use `==` in conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your recent comment clarifying your requirement, I believe you want to maintain an array of pages, and progress to the next page with the same event using a for loop.

```
var pages = ['index1.html','index2.html','index3.html','index4.html'];

$(".button").on("click", function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++){
        if(window.location.pathname == pages[i]){
            if(i == pages.length - 1){
                //at the end, go to first page
                window.location.href=pages[0];
            }
            else{
                window.location.href=pages[i+1];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Though do debug this code and check the values for window.location - it might not be what you expect if you have a long path. You'll need to add the entire relative path (`some/path/index1.html`) to the array if you wish this to work on URLs like the following `www.foo.com/some/path/index1.html`.